# Touchpad not found after sleep mode/close laptop lid after last update

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, laptop, asus

Weird thing happened after my last update on my new laptop (Asus k401l), when it goes to sleep or when I close the lid, the touchpad is disabled and in system **Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad** it says "touchpad not found" in red. Worked fine before the sleep mode came on.

I have tried with no solution:

- using hot keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (was working before sleep mode);
- reinstalling Kubuntu.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

With root privileges, try to create the file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad`. From a terminal window:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad
```

enter you password when prompted and copy/paste this code into Gedit or another text editor:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 su USER -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0' ;;
esac
```

and change the word USER (in the above code) with your actual username (the one that you use to log in to your computer).

Save the file, log out and back in again and test the trackpad after a suspend/resume cycle.